# C++ builder parser issue: [ILINK32 Error] unreselved external

Tags: xml, parsing, c++builder

I am trying to develop a dll in **C++ builder xe**, and I need to parse an `XML file` and for that I use **the parser** of **C++ builder xe** which generate a code that allows me to manipulate the `xml file`.
The problem is I got errors at the compilation caused by generated code.
here is what looks like the generated code:

_

```
di_IXMLDevlinkAbstractionLayer __fastcall GetDevlinkAbstractionLayer(_di_IXMLDocument Doc)
{
  return (_di_IXMLDevlinkAbstractionLayer) Doc->GetDocBinding("DevlinkAbstractionLayer", __classid(TXMLDevlinkAbstractionLayer), TargetNamespace);
};

_di_IXMLDevlinkAbstractionLayer __fastcall GetDevlinkAbstractionLayer(TXMLDocument *Doc)
{
  _di_IXMLDocument DocIntf;
  Doc->GetInterface(DocIntf);
  return GetDevlinkAbstractionLayer(DocIntf);
};

_di_IXMLDevlinkAbstractionLayer __fastcall LoadDevlinkAbstractionLayer(const UnicodeString& FileName)
{
  return (_di_IXMLDevlinkAbstractionLayer) LoadXMLDocument(FileName)->GetDocBinding("DevlinkAbstractionLayer", __classid(TXMLDevlinkAbstractionLayer), TargetNamespace);
};
```

the errorsI get is :

```
  [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::TObject::GetInterface(_GUID&, void *)' referenced from D:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\SESA269906\DESKTOP\DEV\DEVLINKABSTRACTION\DEBUG\WIN32\COOLINGCONFIGDALDLL.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Strhlpr::UnicodeFree(System::UnicodeString&)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\8.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|ustring
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Strhlpr::WideFree(System::WideString&)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\8.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|wstring
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Strhlpr::WideAssign(System::WideString&, System::WideString&)' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES\EMBARCADERO\RAD STUDIO\8.0\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\VCLE.LIB|wstring
```

I think the mistake is the include  in one of the generated file causes the problem.
any ideas?

Comment: Try `#include <System.hpp>` and `#include <System.Internal.hpp>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolve the probleme by unchecking the linker option "Dynamic RTL", in the project options, and "Link with runtime packages"; in the packages options.
I don't know what is the relationship between this and the intial problem...